# MySQL Conditional Query + Control Flow Functions

Tags: mysql

MySQL: 5.5.15-55 Percona Server (GPL), Release 21.0

I'm trying to grab a value from a table by comparing it to three other values (in order). If the value = 'value1' stop, and use that value, if not compare it to 'value2' and so on.

Pseudo-query:

```
SELECT value FROM tbl_variable
IF (WHERE object = 'value1')
ELSE IF (WHERE object = 'value2')
ELSE (WHERE object = 'default');
```

I think I need to use a [Control Flow Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) (Case maybe?), but I'm having issues understanding the syntax.

**EDIT**

Table structure

```
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| var_name    | varchar(50)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| object      | varchar(102)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Final query based on Green Demon's answer.

```
SELECT (CASE 
WHEN object = 'value1' THEN value
WHEN object = 'value2' THEN value 
WHEN object = 'default' THEN value 
END)
AS value
FROM tbl_variables
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
AND var_name = 'NAME'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Not sure I've understood... Do you just want to `SELECT value FROM tbl_variable WHERE object IN ('value1', 'value2', 'default')` or is there more to it than this?

Comment: @SteveChambers No, I need to get the first match.  If value1 matches, I don't want to compare anymore.

Comment: Still trying to understand - what do you want to do with it when a match is found - just `SELECT` it as-is?

Comment: @SteveChambers Correct.  If a comparison matches, I want to SELECT a field from that record (called 'value') and stop the query.

Comment: Ah I see. Looks like you're sorted now (but assume you meant `THEN value1` / `THEN value2` / `THEN default` in the posted query?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE is pretty much the "switch" function of java and c++, which is the "if" statement for comparing the same object against multiple variables. .

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE object WHEN 'value1' THEN 'value1'  
WHEN  'value2' THEN 'value2' 
ELSE 'value3' END;
```

Alternatively, CASE can be used as the "IF" function

```
SELECT CASE WHEN object = 'value1' THEN 'value1'  
WHEN  object = 'value2' THEN 'value2' 
ELSE 'value3' END;
```

EDIT 1:  try

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN object = 'value1' THEN 'value1'  
WHEN  object = 'value2' THEN 'value2' 
ELSE 'value3' END)  AS returnVal
WHERE returnVal IS NOT NULL

LIMIT 1
```

;

The first condition returns only values that are not null, and limit 1 says to stop at first valid record.

Comment: Option 2 works with caveats.  It's returning values for every record in the table.  The record matching a case returns as expected - the rest return NULL.  Is this expected?  I only want to return the the value for the one that matches.

Comment: I see. what you want is the equivalent of C++ switch and break

Comment: I think I've figured it out.  Will post query in the question in a few.

Comment: See updated question.  I was putting my WHERE var_name statements in the WHEN logic before.  I took it out of the CASE, and now it works.  Thanks for your help!